# Using beamer and newicktree: Illegal unit of measure

Tags: beamer

I want to insert a phylogenetic tree into my Beamer presentation, but I am getting an error on compilation: `Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).`

Minimum working example, adapted from the working example on the [newicktree](http://cbr.jic.ac.uk/dicks/software/newicktree/) homepage:

```
%Compile with XeLaTeX for embedded EPS
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{newicktree}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{newicktree}

\drawtree{((My:1,first:1.5):0.5,(\sf newicktree:2,tree!:2.5):0.5):0.5;}

\end{newicktree}


\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If I replace `beamer` with `article` the document compiles without errors. If I let the document finish compiling, the tree it shows is completely incorrect. Is there something different I need to do to get this document to compile with beamer?

If it matters, I am working in TexShop 3.57 on MacOS 10.9

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The example compiles fine if you add the `[fragile]` option after `\begin{frame}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't go into the details why, but the example compiles fine with the `fragile` option. The `\drawtree` is a wrapper around `\pstree` and I believe that also for this command the `fragile` option is needed.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{newicktree}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{newicktree}

\drawtree{((My:1,first:1.5):0.5,(\sf newicktree:2,tree!:2.5):0.5):0.5;}

\end{newicktree}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]